# Sitecore field with standard values not reflecting on item

Tags: templates

This is so weird..
I have an existing template and i created a **new** field with checkbox property. 
i set it "Shared" and seletected the default value as "Selected"

The weird thing is 
when i go to my existing items and see the value
the english version doesnt have the default value where as the French version has it. 
Keep in mind this is a Newly created field. so it has not been modified by me. 
there are 100s of such components and all of them behave the same way..

looks like a sitecore bug - but can some one verify?

**My Template** 
[image: My Template]

**The English version** 
[image: The English version]

**The French version** 
[image: The French Version]

Comment: Have you created a version on the standard values item for both French and English?

Comment: This looks similar to the bug noted in the following link but that bug involves language fallback while this involves a shared field: http://www.xcentium.com/blog/2016/05/11/field-fallback-in-the-new-world-of-sitecore-81

Comment: @RichardSeal Yes. i did. also note that it is shared .

Comment: Was the field changed from normal (versioned) to shared at some point recently (or ever)?

Comment: Do the raw values of the English and French versions reflect the same inconsistency?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the screenshots, it appears that the English version doesn't have a Standard Values. I understand for a Shared field this seems counter-intuitive, but I'd like to see a screenshot of the English version *after* you've installed Standard Values and set the checkbox to true. It'd also be interesting to see if creating a Standard Values in English *automatically* ticks the box due to its shared nature and the existence of a value for the field in French Standard Values.

Assuming it's a bug (It'd be useful to know your Sitecore version number), it would appear that Standard Value resolution does not take trans-language Standard Values into consideration.